# how to do RabbitMQ Spring AMQP 1.2 performance testing?

Tags: performance, rabbitmq, message-queue, spring-amqp, spring-rabbit

I am working on performance testing of RabbitMQ broker using Spring AMQP 1.2 release. Can anyone explain steps for the same and am using Java as client for both Producer and Consumer.

Comment: Can any one please help on this?

Comment: Can you provide more details about exactly what you want to test?

Comment: I want to write 10K Objects into Queue and want to write asynchronous consumer code as well which consumes messages for every 10000 secs. And I want consume only 100 messages at a time, here I want to test performance how many messages are processing for second. If any suggestions on performance testing please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a pretty basic requirement - just invoked one the `RabbitTemplate`'s send methods 10k times, and wire up a `SimpleMessageListenerContainer` to invoke your service (which can be a POJO using the `MessageListenerAdapter`, and play with its [concurrency properties](http://static.springsource.org/spring-amqp/reference/html/amqp.html#containerAttributes) to see the effect on consumption rates.

Comment: Thanks Russell. Here I have one query, how does RabbitMQ server stores the messages, is it file system or database? can you please tell me how to configure database for persisting messages?

Comment: I can only talk to the `Spring-AMQP` project and how it provides common Spring abstractions; for questions about RabbitMQ itself, try their mailing list https://lists.rabbitmq.com/cgi-bin/mailman/listinfo/rabbitmq-discuss

Comment: Thanks Russel for the suggestion, will touch with RabbitMQ team on database management. But, here Spring-AMQP works on RabbitMQ server right? My understanding of Spring-AMQP is it provides the abstract layer for writing producer and consumer. And am using Spring-AMQP for writing producers and consumers instead plain RabbitMQ approach. Please let me know if if am wrong!!!

Comment: Yes. All I am saying is I can't answer questions about how the broker stores its messages.

Answer (score 0):

This can be tested by using RabbitMQ's Java Client Tools which comes with PerfTest: https://www.rabbitmq.com/java-tools.html

PerfTest is a performance testing tool. It starts up zero or more producers and consumers and reports the rate at which messages are sent and received, along with the latency (i.e. time taken for messages to pass through the broker).

More specific info on the link above and here: https://www.cloudamqp.com/blog/load-testing-and-performance-measurements-rabbitmq.html

I hope this helps.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).